# Spring Data JPA does findAll retrieve data from associated table in a onetoone mapping?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA. I have 2 tables as follows:

Investment and Investment_Type. There is a one to one relationship between Investment and Investment_Type.

My Investment class is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Investment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int investmentId;

@NotNull(message = "Cannot be empty")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "investment_type_id")
private InvestmentType investmentType;

@NotNull(message = "Cannot be empty")
private String investmentNumber;

 //getter and setter methods


}
```

My InvestmentType class is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class InvestmentType {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer investmentTypeId;

private String investmentTypeName;

//getter and setter methods
}
```

My InvestmentRepository is as follows:

```
public interface InvestmentRepository extends JpaRepository <Investment, Integer>{

}
```

My controller has the following code:

```
List<Investment> investments = investmentRepo.findAll();
    for(Investment investment:investments){
        logger.info(" Got investment with id "+investment.getInvestmentId());
        if(investment.getInvestmentType() != null){
            logger.info("Investment Type is "+investment.getInvestmentType().getInvestmentTypeName());
        }
        else{
            logger.info("null investment type ");
        }
    }
```

However, the for loop always outputs "null investment type"

So it appears that the findAll method does not retrieve the data from the InvestmentType table to which there is a OneToOne mapping.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to do something explicit in order to also retrieve data from the associated table with the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

one-to-one association is the only one that can not be proxied.Add fetch type lazy and use mappedby on related table colum.

Parent table

```
@NotNull(message = "Cannot be empty")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "investment_type_id")
private InvestmentType investmentType;
```

Related table

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "investment")
private Integer investmentTypeId;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately, that did not work for me. When I add the "@OneToOne(mappedBy = "investment")" the application fails to start.